# Create Ticket in VTiger

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, ticket-system

Once I have a client contact information saved in Support Module, I could get the following things done..

1. Client sends e-mail to suport@company.com
2. Mail Scanner scans, creates a ticket.
3. A notification is sent that email is received by support team to client.
4. Admin assigns the ticket to someone, client recieves an email that the ticket is being assigned.
5. Client replies to the email, the ticket gets updated in the comment.

How ever if I dont have the client information saved, only the ticket is getting created.

How do I auto save the person contact information as soon as someone sends an email to support@company.com?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you need to build a vTiger custom workflow.

https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Workflows

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN-zll3wAeI

All I can offer is the links above. You would then have to either code this yourself with custom code or see if you can set up a workflow and a CRON job in vTiger.

Good Luck